# Discord.py set custom guild prefixes using sqlite3

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot with Python and sqlite3. It's basically a multi-purpose bot that can be used for many things. One of its features is a custom prefix for guilds- however, the bot does not seem to respond to the new prefix I have sent. This is my code:

```
@bot.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def prefix(ctx):
    await ctx.send("**Prefix command configuration:**\n\nSet new prefix: `j!prefix new <prefix>`")
```

The actual **new** command:

```
@prefix.command()
async def new(ctx, new_pr):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT prefix FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
        prefix = cursor.fetchone()
        if prefix is None:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO main(guild_id, prefix) VALUES(?,?)")
            val = (ctx.guild.id, new_pr)
            prefixsetem = discord.Embed(title=f"<:Success:835190431758549043> **{ctx.guild.name}**'s prefix set to `{new_pr}`", description=f"Set by **{ctx.author}**", color=0x03fc45)
            await ctx.send(embed=prefixsetem)
        elif prefix is not None:
            sql = ("UPDATE main SET prefix = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
            val = (new_pr, ctx.guild.id)
            prefixsetem = discord.Embed(title=f"<:Success:835190431758549043> **{ctx.guild.name}**'s prefix updated to `{new_pr}`", description=f"Updated by **{ctx.author}**", color=0x03fc45)
            await ctx.send(embed=prefixsetem)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

And my bot = commands.Bot:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents, help_command=PrettyHelp(active_time=120, color=0xf5b642, ending_note="j! help <command> for information about a command - select reactions to move to next pages or to delete this message", show_index=False, page_left="⏪", page_right="⏩", remove=""))
```

(**prefix** is a variable I set before in the code, called prefix = "j!")

The bot doesn't seem to respond to the new prefix at all; however, the prefix looks like it has been properly stored in my SQLite3 database (called "main"). Am I doing something wrong here, maybe with the part where the bot = commands.Bot is called? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get prefixes per guild by a function.

```
def get_prefix(bot, message):
    db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT prefix FROM main WHERE guild_id = ?", (message.guild.id))
    prefix = cur.fetchone()
    if len(prefix):
        prefix = prefix[0]
    else:
        prefix = "!" #return default prefix if guild not saved in database.
    db.close()
    return prefix
```

And not `commands.Bot`:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, ...)
```

Comment: you could also add the default prefix to the database if it doesn't already exist

Comment: Thanks, that code seems to work, but whenever I try to message my bot in another server (one where the prefix has not been changed), I get this error: `TypeError: command_prefix must be plain string, iterable of strings, or callable returning either of these, not NoneType` (my other server is also in the database) How can I modify this so if the server is in the database but has no prefix, it just defaults to the default prefix?

Comment: You can add a sql command that adds guild prefix to database if prefix not exist (`prefix = "!"` line on top)